# Spring JPA collectionResourceRel default value?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

When using JPA, if skip @RepositoryRestResource automatically made api added "s".

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Integer> {
}
```

Above code made /api/devices api automatically.

```
public interface RadioDataRepository extends JpaRepository<RadioData, Integer> {
}
```

but I cannot use /api/radiodata or /api/radiodatas. Is there a rule for this?

I know that use annotation like below.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "rdata", path = "rdata")
public interface RadioDataRepository extends JpaRepository<RadioData, Integer> {
}
```

But I'm a newbie in Spring and JPA. Please let me know about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Spring Data Rest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/)

> Spring Data REST exposes a collection resource named after the
>   uncapitalized, pluralized version of the domain class the exported
>   repository is handling. Both the name of the resource and the path can
>   be customized using the @RepositoryRestResource on the repository
>   interface.
>
> ...
>
> By default, the exporter will expose your CrudRepository using the
>   name of the domain class. Spring Data REST also applies the [Evo
>   Inflector](https://github.com/atteo/evo-inflector) to pluralize this word.

### [Evo Inflector](https://github.com/atteo/evo-inflector)

> Evo Inflector implements English pluralization algorithm based on
>   Damian Conway's paper [An Algorithmic Approach to English
>   Pluralization](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Plurals.html).

The document has many details, but this seems to provide a good overview of the algorithm to form the pluralized version of a noun:

```
1. Check if the user has defined an inflection for the noun, and , if so, accept that...
        if the word matches a user-defined noun,
                return the user-specified plural form
2. Handle words that do not inflect in the plural (such as fish, travois, chassis, nationalities ending in -ese etc. - see Tables A.2 and A.3)...
        if suffix(-fish) or suffix(-ois) or suffix(-sheep)
        or suffix(-deer) or suffix(-pox) or suffix(-[A-Z].*ese)
        or suffix(-itis) or category(-,-),
                return the original noun
3. Handle pronouns in the nominative, accusative, and dative (see Tables A.5), as well as prepositional phrases...
        if the word is a pronoun,
                return the specified plural of the pronoun

        if the word is of the form: "<preposition> <pronoun>",
                return "<preposition> <specified plural of pronoun>" 
4. Handle standard irregular plurals (mongooses, oxen, etc. - see table A.1)...
        if the word has an irregular plural,
                return the specified plural
5. Handle irregular inflections for common suffixes (synopses, mice and men, etc.)...
        if suffix(-man),      return inflection(-man,-men)
        if suffix(-[lm]ouse), return inflection(-ouse,-ice)
        if suffix(-tooth),    return inflection(-tooth,-teeth)
        if suffix(-goose),    return inflection(-goose,-geese)
        if suffix(-foot),     return inflection(-foot,-feet)
        if suffix(-zoon),     return inflection(-zoon,-zoa)
        if suffix(-[csx]is),  return inflection(-is,-es)
6. Handle fully assimilated classical inflections (vertebrae, codices, etc. - see tables A.10, A.14, A.19 and A.20, and tables A.11, A.15 and A.21 if in "classical mode)...
        if category(-ex,-ices), return inflection(-ex,-ices)
        if category(-um,-a),    return inflection(-um,-a)
        if category(-on,-a),    return inflection(-on,-a)
        if category(-a,-ae),    return inflection(-a,-ae)
7. Handle classical variants of modern inflections (stigmata, soprani, etc. - see tables A.11 to A.13, A.15, A.16, A.18, A.21 to A.25)...
        if in classical mode,
                if suffix(-trix),       return inflection(-trix,-trices)
                if suffix(-eau),        return inflection(-eau,-eaux) 
                if suffix(-ieu),        return inflection(-ieu,-ieux)
                if suffix(-..[iay]nx),  return inflection(-nx,-nges)
                if category(-en,-ina),  return inflection(-en,-ina)
                if category(-a,-ata),   return inflection(-a,-ata)
                if category(-is,-ides), return inflection(-is,-ides)
                if category(-us,-i),    return inflection(-us,-i)
                if category(-us,-us),   return the original noun
                if category(-o,-i),     return inflection(-o,-i)
                if category(-,-i),      return inflection(-,-i)
                if category(-,-im),     return inflection(-,-im)
8. The suffixes -ch, -sh, and -ss all take -es in the plural (churches, classes, etc)...
        if suffix(-[cs]h), return inflection(-h,-hes)
        if suffix(-ss),    return inflection(-ss,-sses)
9. Certain words ending in -f or -fe take -ves in the plural (lives, wolves, etc)...
        if suffix(-[aeo]lf) or suffix(-[^d]eaf) or suffix(-arf),
                return inflection(-f,-ves)

        if suffix(-[nlw]ife),
                return inflection(-fe,-ves)
10. Words ending in -y take -ys if preceded by a vowel (storeys, stays, etc.) or when a proper noun (Marys, Tonys, etc.), but -ies if preceded by a consonant (stories, skies, etc.)... 
        if suffix(-[aeiou]y), return inflection(-y,-ys)
        if suffix(-[A-Z].*y), return inflection(-y,-ys)
        if suffix(-y),        return inflection(-y,-ies)
11. Some words ending in -o take -os (lassos, solos, etc. - see tables A.17 and A.18); the rest take -oes (potatoes, dominoes, etc.) However, words in which the -o is preceded by a vowel always take -os (folios, bamboos)... 
        if category(-o,-os) or suffix(-[aeiou]o),
                return inflection(-o,-os)

        if suffix(-o), return inflection(-o,-oes) 
12. Handle plurals of compound words (Postmasters General, Major Generals, mothers-in-law, etc) by recursively applying the entire algorithm to the underlying noun. See Table A.26 for the military suffix -general, which inflects to -generals... 
        if category(-general,-generals), return inflection(-l,-ls)

        if the word is of the form: "<word> general",
                return "<plural of word> general"

        if the word is of the form: "<word> <preposition> <words>",
                return "<plural of word> <preposition> <words>"
13. Otherwise, assume that the plural just adds -s (cats, programmes, trees, etc.)... 
        otherwise, return inflection(-,-s)
```

### [Online tool to pluralize a word](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/pluralizer/example)

I found this website, which I *believe* uses the same implementation. You can check what would be the pluralized version of a word: http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/pluralizer/example

Comment: FYI. https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/core/EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider.html